# How to include/change compilation and linking flags on per file basis ?

Tags: samba, waf

I am building samba 4.4.5 on HPUX.
which uses waf(python) tool to build the compete source code.
The tool uses various python scripts and wscript to configure and build the samba.
I want to modify includes path/compilation flags for a particular file or modify linking paths for particular library. 
how could i do the same ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Samba gets built, but I can say that `waf configure` will capture everything that is needed by your compiler during the build: environment variables, command line parameters, etc. Then, `waf build` will use the captured data.

So, waf doesn't allow you to change compilation flags for a particular file. You'll have to hack the wscript or get inventive.

Similarly for the linking paths for libraries: take a good look at the configuration options in waf (`waf --help`), you'll probably find a way to enable/disable/configure that kind of thing there.